# Python. Using input and while

Tags: python

**Instructions:** Program needs to ask the user for a number. For example "5". The program outputs the number 15, as 1+2+3+4+5=15.

I am a novice and am stuck at the beginning:

```
n = (input("Insert a number: "))

while n != 0:
```

Please guide me what to do further

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input("Insert a number: "))
nums = range(1,n+1)
print sum(nums)
```

if you want to do the same thing with `while` loop:

```
n = int(input("Insert a number: "))
sum =0
while n>0:
    sum+=n
    n-=1
print sum
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. That helped me :) Tho I needed t use "while". Maybe u know the way with "while" line also?

Comment: you can do it with while too. But python has an inbuilt function sum for exactly this purpose which works on some looping procedure like while. Its shorter to use sum rather than implementing the whole thing again.

Comment: Actually, yes, I can't use this one :( But thanks anyways :)

Comment: @MartinRehkli I just updated my answer to include `while`: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36154645/1199721)

Comment: edited my answer to include while :)

Comment: Helped!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
num = int(input("Choose a number: "))
total = sum(range(num + 1))
```

If you HAVE to do it using a `while` loop, you can do it this way:

```
total = 0
counter = 0
max = int(input("Choose a number: "))

while counter <= max:
    total += counter
    counter += 1

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this code:

```
try:
    nr_in = int(input("Enter some number: "))
    nr_out = 0
    tmp = 0
    while tmp < nr_in:
        tmp += 1
        nr_out += tmp
    print(nr_out)
except:
    print("This is not a number!")
```

This isn't the shortest and most pythonic way, but I think it might be easier to understand for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please can downvoters explain what's wrong?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I am assuming it is because your solution was, as you said, not pythonic and very lengthy. Gareth Webber's answer above is much better.

Comment: This is almost what i was looking for. There's just that one thing. When i enter the number, it shows mu numbers 1-5 and then it sums it. It needs to show just the sum number. 
Thanks!

Comment: @MartinRehkli Oh sorry, that was just for testing, i'll update the post! And if this is helpful to you, please accept the answer!

Comment: I also did'n mention, that "while" needs to be used in code :(

Comment: @MartinRehkli Sorry, I didn't saw that. I've updated my code...

Answer (score -2):

Do you use python 3 or 2? In python2, raw_input is recommended.

Basically all you need is to convert the string to numeric value ...

```
inp = input("number: ")
try:
    n = int(inp)
except ValueError:
    print("Please give me a number")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I use Python 2. But the thing is that I need to use "while" command :S